# php, getimagesize

Tags: php

In server is many pictures, they pictures have names with space, examples: home 3.png, my new car.jpg.
And i need get all images sizes.
Why getimagesize() show errors with those images?

Error:

```
Warning: getimagesize(http://127.0.0.1/img 1.jpg) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found...
```

If i run picture: http://127.0.0.1/img 1.jpg in browser everything good (so link good).

Full code:

```
<?php
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$string = str_get_html('some text some text <img src = "http://127.0.0.1/img 1.jpg" /> text .... ');

foreach($string->find('img') as $e)
    $img[] = $e->src;

$img_1 = getimagesize($img[0]);
print_r($img_1);
?>
```

Comment: Please show the exact code you're using. Also, are you sure using the `http://` wrapper is appropriate here? You are aware of the possibility of accessing files using an absolute filesystem path (much faster)?

Comment: Is the server which is executing that script running on the same server as the image is located on? Otherwise the reason for this error is probably, that you are accessing your local server via 127.0.0.1 but the server is somewhere else where it can't access your server.

Comment: I can't imagine a single instance where shouldn't be referencing loopback like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work with **files**, not urls.

Comment: Using an URL is completely fine. See example 3 in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Answer (score 0):

*Based on my comment:*

Make sure that the server running the php script has actual access to the file. In this case, as you try to get the image from 127.0.0.1, the php server has to be the same server the image is located on.

If you are trying to run this from a remote server, it is of course not working. When you open the path in your browser, you are accessing your local server (on your own computer), but an external server won't be able to access it that way. If it is in your network, use your real IP or host name instead; if it is not in your network either have to make your local server publicially available or simply move the image to somewhere else.